# How to see the AndroidManifest.xml of my imported packages?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

Let's say I have the following import inside my application `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0"
```

I want to see the `AndroidManifest.xml` of this package. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: If the package is an open source project you can look for it in github, otherwise you will have to download the aar file and decompile it.

Comment: @ZachBublil Since the aar file is downloaded during build - shouldn't there be a way to view it directly from Android Studio?

Comment: if you find the answer please update here as well.

Comment: I guess you would like to see what permissions facebook need in your final manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it in your AS,For example,I want to check com.android.support:design-27.0.2's AndroidManifest.xml file

step 1
[image: step 1]

step 2
[image: step 2]

step 3

[image: step 3]

Reedit for step 1

[image]

Comment: Where is `ExternalLibraries` in step 1? I can't find it. Can you take a bigger screenshot w/ full screen.

Comment: I added screenshot which is you need,please check it,hope that will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Download the aar by searching in this website : 
https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:facebook-android-sdk

Then extract the aar file using 7ZIP and you will see the android manifest however, I believe you won't see the full file content due to some protections against reverse engineering.
You can download it as JAR instead and use some tools to try to decompile it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the aar file in the

`cd ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.facebook.android/facebook-android-sdk`

directory， unzip the aar, you will get the file.